# setVisibility not working properly android

Tags: android, android-view, visibility

I'm hiding a layout say `layoutA` and showing another layout, say `layoutB` using the following code:

```
layoutA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layoutB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

The layoutB has an image progressbar which is controlled by a timer. The problem is sometimes, the hidden layout is properly hidden. And sometimes, the part of `layoutA` which is covered by `layoutB` keeps flickering despite being hidden. It is still visible. Also sometimes, it stays visible.

**This is my code:**

```
layoutA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
layoutB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

tmrOTP = new CountDownTimer(60000, 500) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        final int progressToSet = (int) (((60000 - millisUntilFinished)*100)/60000);

        if(!numVerified) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    updateProgressBar(progressToSet);
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            layoutA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            layoutB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tmrOTP.cancel();
        }
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        layoutA.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layoutB.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tmrOTP = null;
    }

}.start();
```

**This is my xml:**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layoutA"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="319dp"
android:layout_height="287dp"
......
......>


<EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtMobile"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_style_g"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0" />



     <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnSendOTP"
         android:layout_width="300dp"
         android:layout_height="55dp"
         android:textSize="23sp"
         android:text="Send OTP"
         android:textColor="#ffffff"
         android:background="@drawable/button_style_g"
         android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
         app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
         android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
         app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
         android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
         app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtMobile"
         android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
         android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layoutB"
    android:visibility="gone"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="319dp"
    android:layout_height="287dp"
    ......
    ......>


<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProgress"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:background="@null"
        ....
        .... />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**This is layoutA**

[image: this is layoutA]

**This is layoutB- NOTE: here the layoutA is hidden except for the part which is covered by the progressbar**

[image: this is layoutB]

Comment: Is Layout B the same ProgressBar layout?

Comment: yea, layoutB contains the progressbar

Comment: share your complete xml

Comment: @sumit, i've added the layoutA xml

Comment: @mrid: Have you tried by setting a background to layoutB's parent layout?

Comment: @JeevaNandhan the parent already has a background. the green background is of the parent only, layoutA and B have no background

Comment: @mrid: give a try by applying a background to layoutB.

Comment: the background is a gradient, it'll be difficult to set a background that will merge with the background. But that shouldn't be the problem ?